# Getting Index of Item in List coming from Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I have this array:

```
var names = [
    "Name1",
    "Name2",
    "Name3"
];
```

I converted this to `Unorder List` for HTML:

```
for(i = 0; i < names.Length; i++){
    text += "<li>" + names[i] + "</li>";
}
text += "</ul>";


document.getElementById("choices").innerHTML = text;
```

Now, I got this:

- Name1
- Name2
- Name3

And I am happy with the result. But now I want if someone click on `Name2` so it `alert` me the index of the value. What I want is it should in Mobile App (Cordova) so that when user click on List Item it will show details on other activity (Some other page).

PS: 
I checked:

```
var index = $( "li" ).index( this );
```

and

```
var index = $("ul li.active").index();
```

But seems like these are not made for me.

May be I should [Dynamically assign ID's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7514924/5737774) to each `<li>` item? What should I do now?

Comment: You really should make it as `'<li onclick="doStuff(' + i + )"'>...` as this way you don't need to do anything

Comment: I was making one more mistake as well: `$("#choices").click(function() {
  // choices is the DOM element that has my all the <li>s.
 
var index = $(this).index();
  $("span").text( "Index is: #" + index );
});` | `#choices` was `<div>` I should use `<li>` instead of `#choices <div> `

Comment: If I am losing lot of reputation because of this post I will delete it. I think the problem is well discussed bellow so you should not downvote it. May be other users got it helpful. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly get `index` using `index` method.

```
$("li").click(function () {
  alert($(this).index());
});
```

If you have multiple `ul` elements on page and you want to bind `click event` to some specific `element` you can do this.

To bind click on element by id

```
$("#YourUlId li").click(function () {
      alert($(this).index());
});
```

To bind click event by class

```
$(".YourUlClass li").click(function () {
      alert($(this).index());
});
```

Comment: I just have one question: **What if I have multiple `<ul>` in same context or file.?**

Comment: You can bind click function to specific `ul li` by `id` or `class`

Comment: Like `$("#YourUlId li").click`

Answer (score 1):

`$( "li" ).index` will return elements index with respect to all li elements in DOM.

You need to use `.index()` with jquery object of clicked element. It will return the elements index in its parent container:

```
var index = $(this).index();
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the id dynamically in for loop

```
for(i = 0; i < names.Length; i++){
    text += "<li id="+i+">" + names[i] + "</li>";
}
```

assign the click event, u will get the id by below code

```
$(li).click(function(){
   alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Comment: Genius, +1 for `text += "<li id="+i+">" + names[i] + "</li>";` Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Using native javascript, you can just create a function that will alert the index of the array value corresponding the li element value/id

First you attach the function on the choices

```
document.getElementById('Name2').setAttribute('onclick','checkIndex(this)');
```

then loop through the array and hunt for the matching array value

```
function checkIndex(item){
  for(i=0;i<names.length;i++){
    if(names[i] == item.innerHTML){ //or item.id
      alert(names.indexOf(names[i]));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank You for the answer. I pick an idea from it. Though I do it with `Array` and not with `DOM <li>s`.

Comment: Glad you got an idea

Answer (score 1):

use `this` for getting the current element

```
<ul>
<li>Male</li>
<li>Female</li>
</ul>

 <script>
$("li").click(function(){
 alert($(this).index())
})
 </script>
```

Comment: Very easy to understand. Thank You. :)

Answer (score 1):

See below working snippet

```js
var names = [
    "Name1",
    "Name2",
    "Name3"
];
var text='<ul>';
for(i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
    text += "<li>" + names[i] + "</li>";
}
text += "</ul>";
document.getElementById("choices").innerHTML = text;

$('li').on('click',function(){
  alert($(this).index())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="choices"></div>
```

Comment: Thank You. +1 for Complete Code Snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I would handle it in a declarative way, using html data-attributes, handled by jquery. see [here](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

Here's an example.

```js
var names = ["jack", "mary", "lou", "andrew"];
var text = "<ul>";
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) { 
  text += "<li data-id='" + i + "'>" + names[i] + "</li>";
}
text += "</ul>";
document.getElementById("choices").innerHTML = text;

$("li").click(function(e){
   alert($(this).data("id"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  My Choice
  <div id="choices"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Of course you can change data-id with whatever you want, or either add other attributes (data-page ? data-txt ? ) and handle all this in a proper way.

Also, dynamically assign ids to your list is a possibility, but I prefer this because I find it more flexible.