# How to increase div id to apply the function

Tags: jquery

```
<button class="btn btn-square uppercase bold blue pull-right" type="submit" 
id="button-1"><i class="icon-eye"></i> Ticket Details</button>
<div class="row d-none" id="content-1"></div>
```

I have to repeat the above code with incrementing the id how should I do that by using this code:

```
$("#button-1").click(function() {
    $("#content-1").toggle("slide");
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically setting div id in JavaScript or jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514924/dynamically-setting-div-id-in-javascript-or-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

This code will do it for id 1 to 10.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $("#button-" + i).click(function () {
        $("#content-" + i).toggle("slide");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, count all the buttons that you need to create a click function for:

```
var button_count = $("button").length; //you may also use class here
```

Then do a loop:

```
for (var i = 0;i<=button_count;i++) {
    $("#button-"+i).click(function () {
        $("#content-"+i).toggle("slide");
    });
}
```

Comment: glad to be of help. i would greatly appreciate if you would mark my answer as accepted or upvote it if it solved your problem. thanks.